# 1 Milllion Integers GroupBy - Occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, random, pandas-groupby

I created 1million random integers between 1 and 100 & wrote the results to a text file.

```
Results_File = open('RandomResults.txt','w')
for i in range(1000000):
    x = random.randint(1,100)
    Results_File.write(str(x) + "," + '\n')
```

Okay that works. But I wanted to find the occurrence of each integer in the entire dataset.

So I imported the file into a new python session and created a dataframe from the data.    ( I also opened the csv & created the header column "A" to help with moving the data around in Pandas.   ( probably wasn't needed)

```
  df = pd.read_csv('RandomNumbers.csv','r') 
  df.sort_values(by=['A'])
```

This is where i'm stuck.   Could someone point me into the right direction?

I want to see how often each number occurs in this random distribution of numbers.

Comment: Why a data frame?  This is a simple list of numbers.  Stuff them into a `collections.Counter` dict, and you'll automatically have your counts.  Alternately, use a `groupby` operation to gather the results?

Comment: @Prune: typically Pandas is more efficient than Python code, since it basically acts as an *interface* to fast C++ functions.

Comment: It was my first thought to put these numbers into a dataframe because I thought I would be using the Groupby operation in pandas.     I didn't know about Collections.Counter. I'm going to read about it now.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do so by first *grouping* by the column, and then calling `.size()`.

So if the column that contains the values is named `'a'`, you can obtain a dataframe that contains the number of elements *per* value, with:

```
df.groupby('a').size()
```

If I for example run the experiment with 10'000 items between `1` and `10`, I got:

```
>>> df.groupby('a').size()
a
1,     1023
10,    1005
2,     1042
3,      951
4,     1046
5,      949
6,     1015
7,     1004
8,      996
9,      969
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This works like a charm.   I'm studying Pandas right now , and couldn't quite figure out how to get over the hump. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps. The `value_counts()` function of pandas does that.

```
df['A'].value_counts()
```